# Netty 4 EventExecutorGroup shutdown

Tags: netty

I am using Netty 4.0.0.Beta2

I have a pipeline which is configured with several handlers, the last of which runs in its own EventExecutorGroup. A little like so:

```
DefaultEventExecutorGroup separateGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup();

ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast(AGGREGATE, new SomeHandler());
pipeline.addLast(ENCODE, new OtherHandler());
pipeline.addLast(extractEventGroup, EXECUTE, new ExecuteHandler());
```

I then configure a ServerBootstrap with this pipeline configuration as a part of the ChannelInitalizer.

As the server runs, I keep a track of all current clients in a ChannelGroup called 'channels'

Later, when I shut the server down, I flush and close all the channels, then call

```
bootstrap.shutdown();
```

That shuts down the NIO EventExecutorGroup, but not the separate DefaultEventExecutorGroup that I have added to the pipeline for my ChannelHandler - meaning the JVM doesn't exit as threads are still active (just waiting, but not released).

I was a little surprised that this wasn't closed as well, so I keep a reference to the DefaultEventExecutorGroup now and manually close that after my bootstrap.shutdown() call:

```
separateEventGroup.shutdown();
```

Have I missed something, or is that the expected behaviour of Netty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not a bug but an expected behavior.  Think about a JVM that runs multiple protocol servers.  Let's say these servers performs disk I/O and you want to limit the number of threads that performs blocking disk I/O across the JVM.  You could create a shared `EventExecutorGroup` for the handlers that perform disk I/O and use it across the multiple protocol servers in the JVM.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are right and this is a bug.. Could you please open a bug-report so we not forget to fix it ?

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues

Comment: This is not true.  Please see my answer.